# Can't add npm packages to stateless .net core 2 Angular template in Service Fabric

Tags: c#, angular, webpack, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm getting an issue when creating a standard Angular 4.0 template with VS 2017 inside service fabric and trying to add any npm package. The one in this example is ngx-loading but I've also tried ng-prime and ng-bootstrap with the same error.

The app builds fine but when i try to deploy it to the SF cluster locally i get an error from Webpack:

```
ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/ngx-loading/src/ngx-loading.component.ngfactory.ts
Module parse failed: c:\Projects\AngularWithSF\Web1\$$_gendir\node_modules\ngx-loading\src\ngx-loading.component.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (13:29)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import * as i2 from 'ngx-loading/src/ngx-loading.component';
| import * as i3 from 'ngx-loading/src/ngx-loading.service';
| const styles_LoadingComponent:any[] = ['.backdrop[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                z-index: 50;\n                position: absolute;\n                top: 0;\n                left: 0;\n                right: 0;\n                bottom: 0;\n                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);\n            }\n\n            \n\n            .spinner-three-bounce[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                width: 70px;\n                text-align: center;\n                position: absolute;\n                top: 0;\n                left: 0;\n                right: 0;\n                bottom: 0;\n                height: 20px;\n                margin: auto;\n                z-index: 51;\n            }\n\n            .spinner-three-bounce[_ngcontent-%COMP%]    > div[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                width: 18px;\n                height: 18px;\n                background-color: #ffffff;\n\n                border-radius: 100%;\n                display: inline-block;\n                -webkit-animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;\n                animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;\n            }\n\n            .spinner-three-bounce[_ngcontent-%COMP%]   .bounce1[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;\n                animation-delay: -0.32s;\n            }\n\n            .spinner-three-bounce[_ngcontent-%COMP%]   .bounce2[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;\n                animation-delay: -0.16s;\n            }\n\n            @-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {\n                0%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0) }\n                40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }\n            }\n\n            @keyframes sk-bouncedelay {\n                0%, 80%, 100% { \n                    -webkit-transform: scale(0);\n                    transform: scale(0);\n                } 40% { \n                    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);\n                    transform: scale(1.0);\n                }\n            }\n\n\n\n            \n\n            .spinner-sk-rotateplane[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                width: 40px;\n                height: 40px;\n                background-color: #ffffff;\n                text-align: center;\n                position: absolute;\n                top: 0;\n                left: 0;\n                right: 0;\n                bottom: 0;\n                margin: auto;\n                z-index: 51;\n                -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;\n                animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;\n            }\n\n            @-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {\n                0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) }\n                50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) }\n                100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)  rotateX(180deg) }\n            }\n\n            @keyframes sk-rotateplane {\n                0% { \n                    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);\n                    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) \n                } 50% { \n                    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);\n                    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg) \n                } 100% { \n                    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);\n                    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);\n                }\n            }\n\n\n\n            \n\n            .spinner-rectangle-bounce[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                width: 50px;\n                height: 40px;\n                font-size: 10px;\n                text-align: center;\n                position: absolute;\n                top: 0;\n                left: 0;\n                right: 0;\n                bottom: 0;\n                margin: auto;\n                z-index: 51;\n            }\n\n            .spinner-rectangle-bounce[_ngcontent-%COMP%]    > div[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                background-color: #ffffff;\n                height: 100%;\n                width: 6px;\n                display: inline-block;\n                \n                -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;\n                animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;\n            }\n\n            .spinner-rectangle-bounce[_ngcontent-%COMP%]   .rect2[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;\n                animation-delay: -1.1s;\n            }\n\n            .spinner-rectangle-bounce[_ngcontent-%COMP%]   .rect3[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;\n                animation-delay: -1.0s;\n            }\n\n            .spinner-rectangle-bounce[_ngcontent-%COMP%]   .rect4[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;\n                animation-delay: -0.9s;\n            }\n\n            .spinner-rectangle-bounce[_ngcontent-%COMP%]   .rect5[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;\n                animation-delay: -0.8s;\n            }\n\n            @-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {\n                0%, 40%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4) }  \n                20% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0) }\n            }\n\n            @keyframes sk-stretchdelay {\n                0%, 40%, 100% { \n                    transform: scaleY(0.4);\n                    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);\n                }  20% { \n                    transform: scaleY(1.0);\n                    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);\n                }\n            }\n\n\n\n            \n\n            .spinner-wandering-cubes[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                width: 60px;\n                height: 58px;\n                font-size: 10px;\n                text-align: center;\n                position: absolute;\n                top: 0;\n                left: 0;\n                right: 0;\n                bottom: 0;\n                margin: auto;\n                z-index: 51;\n            }\n\n            .cube1[_ngcontent-%COMP%], .cube2[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                background-color: #ffffff;\n                width: 15px;\n                height: 15px;\n                position: absolute;\n                top: 0;\n                left: 0;\n                \n                -webkit-animation: sk-cubemove 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;\n                animation: sk-cubemove 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;\n            }\n\n            .cube2[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;\n                animation-delay: -0.9s;\n            }\n\n            @-webkit-keyframes sk-cubemove {\n                25% { -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5) }\n                50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg) }\n                75% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5) }\n                100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg) }\n            }\n\n            @keyframes sk-cubemove {\n                25% { \n                    transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5);\n                    -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5);\n                } 50% { \n                    transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-179deg);\n                    -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-179deg);\n                } 50.1% { \n                    transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg);\n                    -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg);\n                } 75% { \n                    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5);\n                    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5);\n                } 100% { \n                    transform: rotate(-360deg);\n                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);\n                }\n            }  \n            \n            .full-screen[_ngcontent-%COMP%] {\n                position: fixed;\n            }'];
| export const RenderType_LoadingComponent:i0.RendererType2 = i0.╔╡crt({encapsulation:0,
|     styles:styles_LoadingComponent,data:{}});
 @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/components/home/home.component.ngfactory.ts 8:0-108
 @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.browser.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
```

What I've done is added a new SF project with a stateless angular template. I then install ngx-loading via Package Manager Console:

```
npm install --save ngx-loading
```

After that i add the module to app.module.shared.ts:

```
import { LoadingModule } from 'ngx-loading';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        LoadingModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

When i then use the module in my home.component.ts by adding a loader and bool in my home.component.ts:

```
<div class="my-container">
    <ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '14px' }"></ngx-loading>
    //...
</div>
```

And then try to deploy the application locally the error occurs.

The weird thing is this exact approach works perfectly on the Angular template when not created in Service Fabric. I also tried creating the Angular template outside SF and then importing it as a service but it still fails inside SF and runs perfectly outside SF.